# Eclipse not installing app into Genymotion?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, genymotion

I'm trying to test an app from Eclipse (ADT) in Genymotion.

According to the console, everything seems to be ok:

```
[2014-03-15 17:39:44 - TipCalculator] Uploading TipCalculator.apk onto device '192.168.56.101:5555'
[2014-03-15 17:39:44 - TipCalculator] Installing TipCalculator.apk...
[2014-03-15 17:39:46 - TipCalculator] Success!
[2014-03-15 17:39:46 - TipCalculator] \TipCalculator\bin\TipCalculator.apk installed on device
[2014-03-15 17:39:46 - TipCalculator] Done!
```

The Genymotion emulator launches fine and is responsive, but my app is nowhere to be found.

- I have reinstalled Genymotion, deleted all of the virtual devices and readded them.
- The Eclipse plugin appears to be configured ok.
- The Genymotion directory is set in Eclipse preferences.

I'm running the latest version of the ADT and Genymotion (as of 3/15/14)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your app visible in a real device? are you sure you have a MAIN entry in your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Build the app on eclipse and drag the apk on Genymotion to install it , it take only a few seconds and it will surely work.